# Como Dispara vibração no meu device

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8-1

## Como dispara o Vibrator no meu app Windows Phone 8.1 ?

Como por exemplo :

```
 if(==0)
 {
 VIBRAR APARELHO;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o comando `VibrateController` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
import Microsoft.Devices

VibrateController testVibrateController = VibrateController.Default;

if(Vibrar = true)
{
    testVibrateController.Start(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    testVibrateController.Stop();
}
```